# For loop only iterates half way through?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Finally got a button clicking script going with selenium! Thanks everyone who helped. 
I noticed that I programmed the script to click the button 100 times and observed that it only iterated 53 times the first run, and 55 times the second - is there a reason for not looping all the way through?

```
for i in range(100):

    time.sleep(5)
    xpath_merge = '/html/body/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a[1]'
    box6 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_merge)
    box6.click()
```

That's from a secured webpage (cloud database) so don't mind putting up the links here.
Edit: Trying to click on a button 2000 times to merge 2000 duplicate profiles on a database.

Comment: Maybe some kind of rate limiting?

Comment: Possibly you were (or rather your script was) logged out after some time? Try changing `sleep(5)` to a different value and see what happens.

Comment: Whats happening after 53/55 clicks is it throwing error or what?

Comment: Anything less than 5 seconds doesn't give the webpage enough time to load the buttons so the script fails.  I have mine set to 5 seconds, but halfway through its now giving me a cannot find element error

Comment: @KunduK Yes it clicks 53 or so times and throws an error afterwards.. :/

Comment: if possible, it would help if you could provide the error you are getting, that can make it easier to find the problem

Comment: The following is the error that occurs sometimes - strange since it will run a few times successfully, but will randomly present this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a